# How to Mechanize select and click a button by id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

I am trying to submit a login form through mechanize, however what I see on the form is a little strange. There's one form which contains 8 buttons;

```
{buttons
 [button:0x3fcd204e974c type: button name:  value: ]
 [button:0x3fcd204e9684 type: button name:  value: ]
 [button:0x3fcd204e95bc type: button name:  value: ]
 [button:0x3fcd204e94f4 type: button name:  value: ]
 [button:0x3fcd204e942c type: button name:  value: ]
 [button:0x3fcd204e9364 type: button name:  value: ]
 [button:0x3fcd204e929c type: button name:  value: ]
 [button:0x3fcd204e91d4 type: button name:  value: ]}
```

the first of which I'm fairly sure, from counting the buttons and their order from the actual html, is the button that I want to select to submit the login form.

`form.submit` simply returns the same page, but with the password field no longer set, username still set.

I'd like to work out how to specifically select that first button.

`buttons.first.click`, `buttons.firist.submit`, `.select` or `.submit` don't work either.  The actual button's html that I want to 'click' looks like;

```
<button onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(''); __doPostBack('cmdLogin','')" id="cmdLogin" type="button" tabindex="5" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
```

Can you help me understand how to Mechanize select and 'click' the above button. Indidentally I am able to set values for other fields in the page just fine, it's just submitting the form that I'm having trouble with.

Usernames and password logs in successfullly in a real browser.

I cannot see any javascript specifically relating to login on the page, except a script relating to clicking the button if return key is hit:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[rel*="external"]').click(function () { this.target = "_blank"; });
            $(".qhelp").popover();
            $(".no-jump").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });

            $("#div-all-quotes").hide();

            $("#button-all-quotes").click(function () {
                $("#div-all-quotes").toggle();
            });

            $("#txtEnterUserName").keyup(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13){
                    $("#cmdLogin").click();
                     }
            });

            $("#txtEnterPassword").keyup(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13){
                    $("#cmdLogin").click();
                     }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

I wonder if this;

```
button onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(''); __doPostBack('cmdLogin','')
```

js on the button above is stopping me submitting? I cannot find the functions that it relates to running on the page, either through inspector or looking at the foot of the browser loaded html.

Thank you.

Comment: Mechanize doesn't handle javascript, so you're probably looking for selenium/watir/capybara

Comment: As above though @pguardiario, that js only related to hitting the return key, not clicking the button, thus my thoughts are that telling mechanize to click the button should still work?

Comment: No, mechanize doesn't know how to click a button. It can "click" a link, though - which means follow the href and disregard any onclick handlers. In other words, no javascript.

Comment: So i just set the log in fields correctly, set `button` to `buttons.first` which i know is the correct submit button, then called; `agent.submit(form, button)` and same again, simply returns the same page with the password no longer set :(. How can I discern whether this is js interference or not?

Comment: The button has an onclick event. This is a javascript thing. I don't know how to make this more clear, honestly.

Comment: ha ha, re-read, got it, excuse idiocy! thanks @pguardiario !!!